# Streamlit throwing error list index out of range

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using streamlit to create an application. whenever i select an option from select menu it throws an error:

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Traceback:

```
python\python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 338, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)

in <module> get_option(option)

in get_option result = summarise_video(article_url)

in summarise_video video_id = video_url.split("=")[1]
```

But when i give in the data it works fine.

here is to code

````
def get_option(option):
    if option == "Text Summarisation":
        sentence = st.text_area('Enter your text here...')
        st.button('Summarise')
        if st.button:
            st.write("Your Summary")
            result = summarise_text(sentence)
            st.write(result)
    elif option == "Video Summarisation":
        video_url = st.text_input('Enter youtube url here...')
        st.button('Summarise')
        if st.button:
            result = summarise_video(video_url)
            st.write(result)
    else:
        article_url = st.text_input('Enter article url here...')
        st.button('Summarise')
        if st.button:
            result = summarise_video(article_url)
            st.write(result)


option = st.sidebar.selectbox(
    "Select option",  ("Text Summarisation", "Web Scrapping", "Video Summarisation"))

get_option(option)```


Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: ```video_url.split("=")[1]```
video_url is either empty, or does not contain an `=`. 
This is not a streamlit related error this is a logic error in the function `summarise_video`.

Comment: i have tried debugging it. video url contain the value as well as "="

Comment: also the code is functioning properly and is giving the desired results. Just that before entering the url , it is showing this error.

Comment: The stack trace tells you that the error is being thrown in `summarise_video`  when it's trying to split the string. Can you post your "summarize video" method?  Also. Do a print out of the video URL as soon as it's passed in and tell me what values you get for this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: Oh. Nevermind. Just read "also the code is functioning properly and is giving the desired results. Just that before entering the url , it is showing this error." In that case... the code is performing as expected.

Comment: I've included an asnwer below.  Seeing as this is a logic error. I think it would help others if you removed `data-science`, or `artificial intelligence` tags as this is not a data-science or artificial intelligence related question, but has more to do with your URL handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a logic error, rather than a streamlit error. You're not checking if your url link is valid. I've created a small function to check if it's a youtube video. (You might want to look into creating a better one eventually)

```py
import requests
def is_youtube_url(url:str) -> bool:
    try:    
        #Checks if it's a youtube url
        if "youtube.com/watch" not in url: 
            return False
        #Checks if the URL is a valid video
        r = requests.get("https://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ") # random video id
        is_available = "Video unavailable" in r.text
        return is_available
    except:
        return False
```

Additionally. You're not calling `st.button`, you're referencing the function in your if statements. You should be writing `is_button_clicked = st.button("Run")` for example, then checking the truth values of your variable `is_button_clicked`.  Instead you're checking the truth value of `st.button` which is..  a function, so it will always return true.

Change your statement like this.

```py
    else:
        article_url = st.text_input('Enter article url here...')
        is_summarized_button_clicked = st.button('Summarise')
        if is_summarized_button_clicked:
            if is_youtube_url(article_url):
                result = summarise_video(article_url)
                st.write(result)  
            else:  
                st.error("The URL you entered is not a valid youtube URL")
```